# Add a key value to map in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

This is my map "${session.sessionDataMap}". I want to add the client token generated by a function to this map.

```
function clientTokenGeneration() {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "/v1.0/braintree/clienttoken", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization',"${session.sessionDataMap.Access_Token}");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
sessionDataMap.put("clienttoken",response.token); //how can i achieve this i n gsp
}
```

How to add the key value in map in gsp

Comment: Just to make sure. The clienttoken is generated in your gsp file, more specific by a javascript function? And you want to update your session.sessionDataMap on the server?

Comment: Yes my function clientTokenGeneration () is in gsp. SessionDataMap is from the server and which i want to update in gsp. How can i update this map in gsp. Pls help

Comment: What possible good could creating the token on the client do... how could you possibly trust it?   Generate the token on the server, store it in the session, then render it in the page, so that all ajax calls from the client must set it in the header.

Comment: clientToken is the response from this above call. Its not the header(Header uses a different IDS token). I want to set the generated response(response.token) in the sessions sessionDataMap.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve what you're looking for is to make an action in your controller that looks something like this:

```
YourController {

    //...

    def ajax_setClientToken() {
        session.clienttoken = params.token
    }

    //...
}
```

On your .gsp file, in your given JavaScript function `clientTokenGeneration` you can make a call to this action:

```
function clientTokenGeneration() {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "/v1.0/braintree/clienttoken", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization',"${session.sessionDataMap.Access_Token}");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

    xhttp.open("POST", "/ajax_setClientToken?token="response.token, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Alternatively, however, it looks like you're doing your client token generation on the server side. In that case, you might be better off adding `session.clienttoken = <new token>` right into your method that's creating your token.

Comment: I am creating the clientToken in the UI side. I want to make this token available in session.

Comment: @Jayashree Great! The above code will work perfectly then.